# Display Only Unique Records in Left Table of 1:M Join in Access 2010

Tags: join, ms-access

I have a table of properties, a table of land-owners, and a link table to related them.  The relationship between properties and land-owners is one-to-many.  I would like to use a query to build a datasheet view that displays the land-owners joined to each of the properties.  I have been successful at getting the LEFT JOIN to work but I would prefer to display only unique records from the left table in the results (null values in blank cells acceptable).

Current result:

---

```
PID       OWNERID
 1           32
 1           23
 2           45
 2           18
 2           12
 3           98
 3           12
 3           23
```

Desired result:

---

```
PID       OWNERID
 1           32
             23
 2           45
             18
             12
 3           98
             12
             23
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not an sql issue, it is a presentation issue. Where do you intend to present the results? A form? A report? In which version of MS Access?

Comment: Access 2010 (in title).  Presentation is a datasheet / tabular view  - this is a form populated by a query in access (need to maintain ability to sort, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not terribly happy with this, because I think a report would be better for this type of display, but it is one idea. You will only have reduced ability to sort. PID must always be the first sort field or there is no sense in it.

You will need a textbox:

```
=getposition([pid])
```

Some code

```
Function getposition(pos)
    ''Set rs = Screen.ActiveForm.RecordsetClone
    Set rs = Forms!NameOfFormHere.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "pid=" & Nz(pos, 0)
    getposition = rs!ownerid
End Function
```

And conditional formatting:

[image: conditional]

Comment: I'm not sure how this works.  To my understanding the function checks whether the row of a particular PID cell value matches the row of the first occurrence of the particular PID in the table - if it is not then the cell does not display?  Where does the code go?  Why is there a textbox needed?

Comment: The code goes in any module. The textbox is to have something for conditional formatting to check against.

Comment: I added a module to the project and pasted the above code in it.  I added a textbox to the form with the call to the function. I get an error: "You entered a reference that is invalid reference to the RecordsetClone Property".

Comment: The code was a sketch of an approach, change the reference from Screen.ActiveForm to the name of your form, as illustrated above.

Comment: BTW, I am not sure you should be doing this at all, in that I believe that you are losing far more than you are gaining.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  This is working now.  Used a form class object and 'Me.RecordsetClone' to obtain the reference.  Used conditional formatting with the expression as shown.  I may experiment and search the row immediately above a given row to check for an identical PropID - this should allow sorting based on fields other than PropID

Comment: You are mistaking a continuous form for a set of active records. It is not. Anything that you apply will be applied to the current record, but will appear to affect all records. That is why you have to work with bound controls and conditional formatting.